# Exact Phrase Search using CONTAINS clause in Oracle db

Tags: oracle

I have the below query which I expect to return the rows which exactly matches the phrase "My favorite thing"

```
SELECT TestColl.tID, TestMetavalues.*
FROM TestColl, TestMetavalues
WHERE TestColl.tID=TestMetavalues.tID 
AND ( (CONTAINS(TestFullText,'(My favorite thing)') > 0 )) ;
```

But the above query returned the rows which had only "My favorite thing" and also rows which had "favorite"

the table TestColl has a a BLOB column - TestFullText

I want the query to display only those rows which has the exact "My favorite thing"

How to achieve this?

I tried these solutions but no luck

[Expecting exact results when using contains clause in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295922/expecting-exact-results-when-using-contains-clause-in-oracle)

[search criteria difference between Like vs Contains() in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700795/search-criteria-difference-between-like-vs-contains-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TestColl.tID, TestMetavalues.*
FROM TestColl, TestMetavalues
WHERE TestColl.tID=TestMetavalues.tID 
AND TestColl.TestFullText LIKE '%My favorite thing%' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the query to display only those rows which has the exact "My favorite thing"

If that's so, don't you, actually, want a simple

```
SELECT TestColl.tID, TestMetavalues.*
FROM TestColl, TestMetavalues
WHERE TestColl.tID = TestMetavalues.tID 
  AND TestFullText = 'My favorite thing';
```

Why would you use Oracle Text for that?

Answer (score 0):

A domain index doesn't work like that.  We're indexing keywords in the source text, so we wont actually be storing "My favourite thing", we'll be storing "my" and "favorite" and "thing" and so on.

But you can still get the benefit by using the index as an initial filtering mechanism, eg

```
SQL> create table t ( x varchar2(1000));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values ('These are my medium stuff');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('These are stuff I hate');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('These are other things');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('These are semi FAVORITE things');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t select * from t;

4 rows created.

SQL> insert into t select * from t;

8 rows created.

SQL> insert into t select * from t;

16 rows created.

SQL> insert into t select * from t;

32 rows created.

SQL> insert into t select * from t;

64 rows created.

SQL> insert into t select * from t;

128 rows created.

SQL> insert into t select * from t;

256 rows created.

SQL> insert into t select * from t;

512 rows created.

SQL> --
SQL> -- our special rows
SQL> --
SQL> insert into t values ('These are a few of My Favorite Things');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('Some other of My Favorite Things');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> create index ix on t (x )
  2  indextype is ctxsys.context;

Index created.

SQL>
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('','T')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> set autotrace on explain
SQL> select count(*) from t
  2  where CONTAINS(x,'My Favorite Things') > 0;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       258

1 row selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2114225437

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE  |      |     1 |    26 |            |          |
|*  2 |   DOMAIN INDEX   | IX   |   130 |  3380 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("CTXSYS"."CONTAINS"("X",'My Favorite Things')>0)

SQL>
SQL> select * from t
  2  where CONTAINS(x,'My Favorite Things') > 0
  3  and x like '%My Favorite Things%';

X
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
These are a few of My Favorite Things
Some other of My Favorite Things

2 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1339481741

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |      |     6 |   156 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T    |     6 |   156 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   DOMAIN INDEX              | IX   |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("X" LIKE '%My Favorite Things%' AND "X" IS NOT NULL)
   2 - access("CTXSYS"."CONTAINS"("X",'My Favorite Things')>0)

SQL>
SQL>
```

So the domain index got us down to 258 candidate rows, then the additional LIKE got us down to the 2 rows we wanted.